# Git: alias "head" to "HEAD" using symbolic-ref

Tags: git

On a case-insensitive file system, I can reference `head` in git commands and it works like `HEAD`.

```
git rebase -i head~4
```

On a case-sensitive system, I have to reference `HEAD` exactly.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

I miss the ease with which my fingers can spit out `head` without reaching for Shift, and I reference `HEAD` frequently enough that I'd like to alias `head` to it.

I found a way to do this, but it has a couple drawbacks.

```
git symbolic-ref head HEAD
```

I'd have to manually set this up in each repo (though maybe there's a way I can use templates to do it automatically upon `git init`).

I also don't understand some of the `git symbolic-ref` behavior. For example, I can create an arbitrary alias to a ref,

```
$ git log -1 my-feature
5bb7f1e add new feature
$ git symbolic-ref foo my-feature
$ git log -1 foo
5bb7f1e add new feature
```

And according to the `git-symbolic-ref` man page, I can also delete the symbolic-ref, but I can't get that to work:

```
$ git symbolic-ref --delete foo
error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'foo'
```

What am I misunderstanding about symbolic-refs? Is this a bad way to use them?

---

*Update*

If I create the `head` ref as:

```
git symbolic-ref --delete "refs/heads/head"
```

then it lives in `.git/refs/heads/head` (rather than `.git/head` as it did in my original attempt). I can still reference it as `head`,

```
git log -1 head
```

and symbolic-ref updates/deletes work as expected

```
git symbolic-ref --delete refs/heads/head
```

Comment: Basically, symbolic refs don't quite work right. They act like symlinks (unsurprising, since `HEAD` was originally actually a symlink!). To delete one that's not under `refs/`, through Git commands, you can use `git update-ref -d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the existing `@` synonym, `git log @{-1}` to show your recent checkout's history will be faster than `git log head@{-1}`, `git show @~` to show your worktree's gp commit faster than `git show head~`.

The spotty rejection of refnames not starting `refs/` is I think an artifact, git uses such refnames internally but they're like reserved names in programming languages, any time you get away with using one for your own purposes you're living in a state of sin.

Comment: While the `@` synonym is nice to know about (thanks for that), I still find `head` easier+faster to type (no Shift chord, no reaching for the number row). Maybe surprising, since I'll be reaching up around that area for the `~` anyway, but I can type `head` without thinking about it and then I'm free to focus on `~4` or whatever. On the other note, I still can't get `git symbolic-ref --delete` to work with any variation on the symbolic-ref name or its contents, even if the contents look like `ref: refs/heads/my-feature`.

Comment: It's not the contents, it's the refname itself.  names outside the refs/ hierarchy are for internal use, as I say the rejection of those is spotty, git doesn't want to make it impossible to use them, just annoying enough to get you to reconsider.  To delete the ref named `head`, delete `.git/head` or if you've done a `git pack-refs --all` that won't exist,  edit the lines out of `.git/packed-refs`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That helped me realize I could create my ref as `refs/heads/head` and get the behavior I expected.

Comment: That's a good idea, but make it a tag, `git symbolic-ref refs/tags/head HEAD`.  Making it a branch will cause `git checkout` to "attach" `HEAD` to it, to making `HEAD` a symbolic ref to it so when `git commit` updates `HEAD` the ref redirects the update to the branch tip.

Comment: Ah, good call. I tried it out, checking out `head` as a branch, adding something, then attempting `git commit`, and got: `fatal: multiple updates for 'HEAD' (including one via symref 'refs/heads/head') are not allowed`. Changing it to a tag works better.